# Match all instances in string using regex with multiple groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a json dump as follows:

```
{
    "field1": "1234b077-fb81-4d5b-adf3-123cdb1b56cf",
    "field2": "111aa3f8-1cc3-4a75-9ad6-912a1d40781b",
    "field3": "c2b75f2d-85ef-4c7c-a111-5d2a41442dc3",
    "field4": "262d6922-53cf-4f9d-93b7-d6bae8711192"
}
```

And a regex `[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}`

I want to display all matches (in fact all field's value are matched) with the following Python code

```
import re

regex = r'[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}'
j = """{
    "field1": "1234b077-fb81-4d5b-adf3-123cdb1b56cf",
    "field2": "111aa3f8-1cc3-4a75-9ad6-912a1d40781b",
    "field3": "c2b75f2d-85ef-4c7c-a111-5d2a41442dc3",
    "field4": "262d6922-53cf-4f9d-93b7-d6bae8711192"
}"""

re.search(regex, j)
```

When executing, it only gives me the field1's value

```
<re.Match object; span=(24, 60), match='1234b077-fb81-4d5b-adf3-123cdb1b56cf'>
```

I don't know if I miss something to print all.

[**Updated**] `re.findall()` doesn't give expected result.

```
pattern = re.compile(regex)
re.findall(pattern, j)
```

Result is not expected, it is something like this

`['adf3-', '9ad6-', 'a337-', '93b7-']`

Comment: I made the problem statement a little more minimal by removing the json dumping part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.finditer` to iterate over each non-overlapping occurrence:

```
import re

regex = r'[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}'
data = """{
    "field1": "1234b077-fb81-4d5b-adf3-123cdb1b56cf",
    "field2": "111aa3f8-1cc3-4a75-9ad6-912a1d40781b",
    "field3": "c2b75f2d-85ef-4c7c-a111-5d2a41442dc3",
    "field4": "262d6922-53cf-4f9d-93b7-d6bae8711192"
}"""


for line in re.finditer(regex, data):
    print(line.group(0))
```

Prints:

> ```
> 1234b077-fb81-4d5b-adf3-123cdb1b56cf
> 111aa3f8-1cc3-4a75-9ad6-912a1d40781b
> c2b75f2d-85ef-4c7c-a111-5d2a41442dc3
> 262d6922-53cf-4f9d-93b7-d6bae8711192
> ```

[See pyfiddle here for demonstration](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c0f6b9d2-3f0d-48ef-b75a-ca76410c7cc6/?i=true)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method, which finds all instances, not just the first, as `re.search` does.

`re.findall` unfortunately also includes match groups which you have in your pattern -- those parts with parens.

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups;** this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

Probably `re.finditer` is a better choice for your use case.

Comment: `re.findall()` gives me something like this `['adf3-', '9ad6-', 'a337-', '93b7-']`